# Objective-c negative Hex values

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, nsdata

I have the following category method on NSData. I'm trying to extract the bit field at the given index and have it return as an NSNumber. I have it working perfectly for all positive but I need it to work with negative numbers as well.

My Implementation looks as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSData (ExternalDevices)
@end
@implementation NSData (ExternalDevices)
- (NSNumber *)extractLittleEndianBitFieldAtIndex:(int)index forLength:(int)length
{

    //This function has limitations on the "length" parameter that are not yet know/defined
    //These limitations are due to the max size of "NSInteger intData" defined below

    int first_byte = index/8;                             //Index of the first byte containing this bit field
    int last_byte = (length+index-1)/8;                          //Index of the last byte containing this bit field
    int byte_length = last_byte - first_byte + 1;                   //number of bytes containing this bit field

    Byte *byteArray = (Byte*)malloc(byte_length);
    memcpy(byteArray, [[self subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(first_byte, byte_length)] bytes], byte_length);

    NSInteger intData = *((NSInteger *)byteArray);

    free(byteArray);
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:intData];
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromHexString:(NSString *)string
{
    string = [string lowercaseString];
    NSMutableData *data= [NSMutableData new];
    unsigned char whole_byte;
    char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};
    int i = 0;
    NSUInteger length = string.length;
    while (i < length-1) {
        char c = [string characterAtIndex:i++];
        if (c < '0' || (c > '9' && c < 'a') || c > 'f')
            continue;
        byte_chars[0] = c;
        byte_chars[1] = [string characterAtIndex:i++];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [data appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];

    }

    return data;
}
@end



@interface Testing:NSObject
@end
@implementation Testing


- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataFromHexString:@"e30b"];
            NSLog(@"%@ should be 3043", [data extractLittleEndianBitFieldAtIndex:0 forLength:16]);
        }

        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataFromHexString:@"46e0"];
            NSLog(@"%@ should be -8122", [data extractLittleEndianBitFieldAtIndex:0 forLength:16]);
        }

        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataFromHexString:@"f208"];
            NSLog(@"%@ should be 2290", [data extractLittleEndianBitFieldAtIndex:0 forLength:16]);
        }

        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataFromHexString:@"10e6"];
            NSLog(@"%@ should be -6640", [data extractLittleEndianBitFieldAtIndex:0 forLength:16]);
        }

        {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataFromHexString:@"018900"];
            NSLog(@"%@ should be 137", [data extractLittleEndianBitFieldAtIndex:8 forLength:16]);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [[Testing alloc] init];
    }
}
```

The following website seems to always yield the results I want under INT16 - Little Endian (BA)

http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/miscellaneous/online-hex-converter.html

Although it is important to note that not every number I work with will be an INT16

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
NSInteger intData = *((NSInteger *)byteArray);
```

is your key problem for two reasons:

1. `byteArray` may be shorter (or less likely, longer) than an `NSInteger` and you'll end up reading garbage. E.g. if `byteArray` is 2 bytes as in your examples and `NSInteger` is 4 bytes - which it will be in 64-bit - you'll read two bytes of garbage.
2. If you are converting signed values you need to sign-extend the value - that is replicate the sign bit into the higher unused bits. E.g. if you are converting a signed 16-bit field into a 32-bit signed value then the upper 16-bits need to be a replication of the most significant bit of the 16-bit value, so 0x7000 -> 0x00007000 and 0x8000 -> 0xFFFF8000.

You need to come up with an algorithm that handles these issues. You may find it easier to do the conversion a byte at a time using masking (and'ing), or'ing and shifting.

HTH